# "This pamphlet says..." or "In this pamphlet says..."?

Tags: grammar

I know that in the following sentence, the pronoun "it" is used in an incorrect way (repetitious pronoun):
In this pamphlet, **it** says that campers should bring their own tents and blankets.

How should I correct the mistake?
a: **In** this pamphlet says that...
b: This pamphlet says that...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sentence "In this pamphlet, it says that..." is completely correct.

"It says..." is an impersonal construction.

Examples of usage in native-speaker texts:

["In the report it says 156 acres were sown..."](https://books.google.com.ua/books?id=yfAkAQAAIAAJ&pg=PA245&lpg=PA245&dq=%22in+the+report+it+says%22&source=bl&ots=T9t_9J6qu6&sig=RMOzPYPwhe84Jm4WKesWcXJmdaI&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiVjLuWr_3YAhXE3SwKHT35DYwQ6AEIKDAA#v=onepage&q=%22in%20the%20report%20it%20says%22&f=false) (said by an Australian Member of Parliament).

["In the report it says funding was granted."](https://www.independent.ie/regionals/droghedaindependent/news/council-has-no-plans-to-take-over-carstown-36316064.html) (said by an Irish councilman)

Granted, it's a bit colloquial. But not incorrect.

"The report says that..." is simply more formal. It is a better choice in a written text when you need to be proper and formal.